# Trigger after delete THEN UPDATE mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

i want make trigger after delete on orders_foods

my logic is: `delete from orders_foods where id=;id` then update price on orders price = sum (orders_foods.price ) where id=orders_foods.order_id

this my code i try befor but got error `#1363 -`

```
Delimiter //  
CREATE TRIGGER ubah_tot_harga AFTER DELETE ON orders_foods
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE harga_1 int default 0;
     SELECT SUM(price) into harga_1 fROM `orders_foods` WHERE order_id = new.order_id;

     update  orders
      set price= harga_1
      where id=old.order_id;
      END
//
delimiter ;
```

[orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2ILH.png)
[orders_foods table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LRL7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of new.order_id, you need to use old.order_id. because after delete there is no new.order_id there is only old.order_id.

```
Delimiter //  
CREATE TRIGGER ubah_tot_harga AFTER DELETE ON orders_foods
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE harga_1 int default 0;
     SELECT SUM(price) into harga_1 fROM `orders_foods` WHERE order_id = old.order_id;

     update  orders
      set price= harga_1
      where id=old.order_id;
      END
//
delimiter ;
```